# sendRedirect not working as expected

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 controllers involved in a fairly simple flow. One of them does some processing and POSTS to the other which then redirects to a page that renders. The redirect is failing but with no errors. To simplify my use case and identify the issue, I have collapsed it down to these 3 methods -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/provider/g1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void g1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.debug("In g1. posting to pr1");

    try {
        URI location = restTemplate.postForLocation("http://localhost:8082/provider/pr1", null);
        logger.debug("post response=" + location.toString());
    } catch (RestClientException re) {
        logger.error("Unable to post to pr1.");
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value="/provider/pr1", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void pr1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.debug("In pr1. sending redirect to rd1");
    // return "redirect:/provider/rd1";

    try {
        String rd1Path = "http://localhost:8082/provider/rd1";
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(rd1Path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error redirecting to rd1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/provider/rd1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void rd1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.debug("In rd1");
}
```

I have tried both the relative path and the fully qualified path and its the same result.

- I can access /provider/rd1 and get the expected response.
- When I access /provider/g1, I am expecting to get redirected to /provider/rd1.

The output is -

```
In g1. posting to pr1.  
In pr1. sending redirect to rd1
post response=http://localhost:8082/provider/rd1
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how I can make this work.
Thank you,
SR

Comment: It looks like expected behavior for me. What's exactly wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [javadoc of `RestTemplate#postForLocation(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). It states

> Create a new resource by POSTing the given object to the URI template,
>   and returns the value of the Location header.

Remember that POST-REDIRECT-GET is a very common pattern in web applications.

So you make an HTTP POST request to `http://localhost:8082/provider/pr1` which returns a 302 response with a `Location` header set to `http://localhost:8082/provider/rd1`, which is what is printed.

Your `rd1` is never invoked because no request is ever sent that matches its mapping.

You might be looking to use another `postXxx` method of `RestTemplate`.

Comment: @Spring You can't carry over request parameters. They only live for the duration of one request. You'll want to look into flash attributes. In your case, you've sent the POST and received the REDIRECT response containing the `Location` header, you just haven't done the GET on that location URI.

Comment: Thanks for responding back. In my actual working code, I do need to pass parameters to the POST and have the redirected-to URL carry request parameters as well. In this case, I trimmed all that down just to ensure the GET->POST->Redirect->GET was working properly. I changed the postxxx to a postForObject and had the same result. Since for this use case, I was not passing any parameters, I figured any of the RestTemplate's postxxx methods that triggered `pr1()` was good enough. It looks like `pr1()` is getting invoked. I was thinking the `sendRedirect()` was returning a 302 causing the browser

Comment: ... to perform a GET on the `location` which is `/provider/rd1`. How do I get the request to invoke `rd1()`, get sent? Thank you

Comment: @spring You send another GET request with the `RestTemplate` to the URI that you retrieve, whichever is appropriate, `getForEntity` or `getForObject` or use `exchange`.

Comment: Are you saying in my first GET method `g1()` which invokes the post method, I need to explicitly perform a GET on the location returned by the POST? My understanding was that the `sendRedirect()` in the `pr1()` would issue a 302 which would cause the browser to come back and access the value in the location header (`/provider/rd1`). Thank you.

Comment: @spring5150 The 302 is returned to the `restTemplate` call in the `g1` method, not to the browser client.

Comment: @spring5150 So yes, you would need to send a new GET to the URI returned or propagate the 302 to the browser by returning a 302 response with the `Location` header set to your URI value.

Comment: If I make a separate GET request in `g1()` or propagate the 302, it works. But it requires me to know what is being done with the POST or what `pr1()` is doing. In my actual implementation, everything including and past the POST is being handled by a  different controller. It so happens I have control over both pieces of code but what if I didn't? If I was only responsible for everything past the POST, is there a way I could perform a redirect in `pr1()` without expecting `g1()` to send back the 302? Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @Spring with a pattern like this, your goal, IMO, is to POST some resource. You've done that. It's up to you to decide what to do with the 302 response. Try to GET that resource or ignore it.

Comment: You are right. The first part of posting the resource is fine. Lets say I want to be able to ignore the response coming back from the POST. And I only have control over what happens in the POST method (`pr1()`) and beyond. What if I needed to redirect to a different location after some processing in my POST method. Is there a way I can have a 200 returned by the call to g1(), and have the browser perform the POST, so that it gets the 302 and performs a GET on the location? Thanks

Comment: @spring HTTP is request-response protocol. You send one request, you get back one response. You can't return a 200 and expect the browser to make a new request. It wouldn't be following the HTTP spec. If you don't control `g1()` you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just do :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/provider/pr1", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String pr1() {
    logger.debug("In pr1. sending redirect to rd1");
    return "redirect:/provider/rd1";

}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what is "OP's"

Comment: Opening post or Original post(er).

Comment: no it is different, the signature method is different. the try catch is even unnecessary.

Comment: Returning a String with `"redirect:"` prefix will, normally, use the `ViewResolver` to resolve a `View` that calls `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`. Before your edit, returning `null` will make Spring assume that the response was handled by the handler method. That is equivalent to a `void` return type.

Comment: I removed the 'return null' because the try/catch was unnecessary. Now, this doesnt work, it always worked for me.

Comment: The issue isn't the redirect. That works fine. OP is just misinterpreting their results.